# pgfplotstabletypeset with the use of multirow and the vertical line problem

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, multirow, multicolumn

Please bear with my clumsy codes here. I am using `multicolumn` and `multirow` to custom-made a header but are having trouble. I will use an example csv file to illustrate what I am trying to do. My csv file (with the original header row) is listed below as `scientists_names.csv`

```
name,surname,age,sex,birthday
Albert,Einstein,135,male,3/14/1879
Marie,Curie,146,female,11/7/1867
Thomas,Edison,168,male,2/11/1847
```

My Latex codes :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

%use the package of pgfplotstable
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma, header=true,
    string type,
    columns/name/.style={column type={|c}},
    columns/surname/.style={ column type={|c}},
    columns/age/.style={ column type={|c}},
    columns/sex/.style={ column type={|c}},
    columns/birthday/.style={ column type={|c|}},
every head row/.style={ 
output empty row,
before row={
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|>{\columncolor{cyan}}c}{ } & \multicolumn{3}{>{\columncolor{cyan}}c| }{Basic Info}  \\
\hhline{~~---} 
\rowcolor{cyan}
 & & Age & Sex & \\
\rowcolor{cyan}
\multirow{-2}{*}{Name} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Surname} & in years & M or F &  \multirow{-2}{*}{Birthday}
\\
}, 
after row={ 
\hline 
} 
},
    every last row/.style={after row=\hline},
    ]{scientists_names.csv}
\end{document}
```

The resulting table :

[image]

I actually want :

[image]

Namely, restore the partial masking on "Name", and "Surname", and remove the vertical line between "Sex" and "Birthday", which I thought would have been masked by rowcolor. (and possible move "Birthday" down to the middle as I did with Name and Surname.)
Any idea will be appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Please remove all the `<br/>` from your code so that people can compile your example.

Comment: Write the multi-row entries as part of the third row using a negative row number (see manual or tidy up your code so somebody can demonstrate). Right now, the row colour is overwriting the bottom half of those entries.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean about the `Birthday`. If you want it vertically centred, why haven't you used a multi-row here?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, cfr ! Still, the partial line underneath Basic Info from \hhline is not shown. The line is still being overwritten by \rowcolor. I will keep searching for solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your code won't compile as it stands, I've edited a minimal amount to demonstrate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{\columncolor{cyan}}c}{ } & \multicolumn{3}{>{\columncolor{cyan}}c|}{Basic Info}  \\\hline
    \rowcolor{cyan}
      &   & Age & Sex & Birthday\\
    \rowcolor{cyan}
    \multirow{-2}{*}{Name} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Surname}& in years & M or F & \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: coloured rows]

[Obviously not at all tidy.]

Recommendation: consider using `booktabs` for better quality tables.